# How do I set logging to debug level

Tags: r, logging

By default, the package `logging` only processes messages at level INFO. Now I want to log DEBUG messages, too. From the [tutorial](http://www.google.com) I adapted the following snippet:

```
library(logging)    
logReset()
addHandler(writeToConsole)
setLevel("DEBUG", getHandler("writeToConsole"))
getHandler("writeToConsole")[["level"]]==loglevels["DEBUG"]
#TRUE
loginfo("this is an info")
#2018-06-15 13:04:40 INFO::this is an info
logdebug("this is a debug note.")
# nothing happens
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you looked into package `futile.logger`. It does exactly what you want with command like `flog.debug`, `flog.warn` etc. . Also have `flog.threshold`.

Comment: Thanks, will look into it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the context of `logging` package, the criticality levels are set for both, for the logger and for the handler objects. In your code you use global logger and a custom handler, where the minimal level of the logger conditions the handling levels is 'INFO'.

After `logReset()` you reset the root logger and remove all default handlers:

```
logReset()
getLogger()[['level']] # accessing the root logger
# INFO 
# 20 
with(getLogger(logger=''), names(handlers))
# character(0)
```

Hence your code:

```
library(logging)  
logReset()
addHandler(writeToConsole)
setLevel("DEBUG", getHandler("writeToConsole"))
getHandler("writeToConsole")[["level"]]==loglevels["DEBUG"]
#TRUE
loginfo("this is an info")
# 2021-11-11 17:35:25 INFO::this is an info
logdebug("this is a debug note.")
# nothing
```

can be adjusted as follows (run after execution of your script):

```
getLogger()[['level']]
# INFO 
# 20
setLevel('DEBUG') # or setLevel('DEBUG', container = '') where it is clear that the root logger is being accessed
getLogger()[['level']]
# DEBUG 
# 10 
logdebug("this is a debug note.")
# 2021-11-11 17:36:55 DEBUG::this is a debug note.
```

Another simpler way is to use `basicConfig()` for the root logger setting it like:

```
logReset()
basicConfig('DEBUG')
loginfo("this is an info")
# 2021-11-11 17:37:43 INFO::this is an info
logdebug("this is a debug note")
# 2021-11-11 17:37:43 DEBUG::this is a debug note
```

or yet another option, with dedicated logger object:

```
logReset()
addHandler(writeToConsole, logger='my_logger')
lrc <- getLogger('my_logger')
lrc$level
# NOTSET 
# 0 
lrc$setLevel('DEBUG')
lrc$level
# DEBUG 
# 10 
setLevel('INFO', lrc$handlers$writeToConsole)
lrc$debug("test")
# nothing
setLevel('DEBUG', lrc$handlers$writeToConsole)
lrc$debug("test")
# 2021-11-11 17:38:32 DEBUG:my_logger:test
```